# If Statement within Case of Switch - JS

Tags: javascript, if-statement, serena

Can you use IF statements within a case of a Switch.

Both of the first statements of each case work fine, but the else IF statements do not :s

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
switch (units) {
    case "Days" :
            if (CarryQuantity > 5)  {MakeFieldInvalid("CARRY_OVER", "You can only carry over a maximum of 5 days"); 
                }

                else if (CarryQuantity = 0) { MakeFieldInvalid("CARRY_OVER", "The value of holiday carry-over days must be greater than zero"); 
                }

                    else  {MakeFieldValid("CARRY_OVER");
                }

        break;
    case "Hours" :
            if (RGBCarryQuantity > 40)  {MakeFieldInvalid("RGB_CARRY_QUANTITY_2", "You can only carry over a maximum of 40 hours.");
                }

                else if (RGBCarryQuantity = 0)  {MakeFieldInvalid("RGB_CARRY_QUANTITY_2", "The value of holiday carry-over hours must be greater than zero");
                }

                    else {MakeFieldValid("RGB_CARRY_QUANTITY_2");
                }

        break;
    default :
        MakeFieldValid("CARRY_OVER");
        MakeFieldValid("RGB_CARRY_QUANTITY_2");
}

}
```

Comment: This looks odd. I would refactor the case statements to a function and then just call the function.

Comment: *"Can you use IF statements within a case of a Switch."* Yes, you can. But your `else if` is failing for the reasons described by the linked question's answers.

Comment: Thank you! should have figured that one out myself!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Please note that '=' is an assigment operator. For comparing values, use either equality '=='  or '===' which is the identity operator.

So you have problem in the else if statements:

```
else if (CarryQuantity = 0)
```

that should be:

```
else if (CarryQuantity == 0)
```

which handles automatic type conversion or

```
else if (CarryQuantity === 0)
```

which can be used if CarryQuantity is a number and not a string.

Comment: Hmm, I'd be interested in the reason of the downvote. I could then correct my answer...

Answer (score -2):

If it runs, then the code is valid... You are saying *can it*. If the else's aren't Running, then no it cant.